# mpi does not work without internet connection

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am using MacBook Air (M2,2022) to run the codes with Rmpi and doMPI in R. However, without wifi connection, I got `Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = rscript, slavearg = args, nslaves = count,  :MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error.`

Here is my code:

```
library(Rmpi)
library(doMPI)

N <- 1000

print(mpi.universe.size())
cl <- startMPIcluster(comm = 3, count = 4)
registerDoMPI(cl)

system.time(
  results <- foreach(j=1:100,.combine='rbind') %dopar% {
    ind.sim <- sample(c(1:N), N, replace = T)
    print(j)
  }
)

mpi.close.Rslaves(comm=cl$comm)

mpi.quit()
```

With internet (wifi) connection, the code runs with warning message `Warning message: In system(paste("ls", logfile), TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : running command 'ls *.64320+3.*.log 2>/dev/null' had status 1`.

Without internet connection, I got the following and then R hangs:

```
> library(Rmpi)
> library(doMPI)
Loading required package: foreach
Loading required package: iterators
> 
> N <- 1000
> 
> print(mpi.universe.size())
[1] 8
> cl <- startMPIcluster(comm = 3, count = 4)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
At least one pair of MPI processes are unable to reach each other for
MPI communications.  This means that no Open MPI device has indicated
that it can be used to communicate between these processes.  This is
an error; Open MPI requires that all MPI processes be able to reach
each other.  This error can sometimes be the result of forgetting to
specify the "self" BTL.

  Process 1 ([[58990,2],3]) is on host: yozuis-MacBook-Air
  Process 2 ([[58990,1],0]) is on host: yozuis-MacBook-Air
  BTLs attempted: vader self

Your MPI job is now going to abort; sorry.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64042] [[58990,2],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64043] [[58990,2],1] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64044] [[58990,2],2] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64045] [[58990,2],3] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:63980] [[58990,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = rscript, slavearg = args, nslaves = count,  : 
  MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_dpm_dyn_init() failed
  --> Returned "Unreachable" (-12) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[yozuis-MacBook-Air:64043] *** An error occurred in MPI_Init
[yozuis-MacBook-Air:64043] *** reported by process [3865968642,1]
[yozuis-MacBook-Air:64043] *** on a NULL communicator
[yozuis-MacBook-Air:64043] *** Unknown error
[yozuis-MacBook-Air:64043] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[yozuis-MacBook-Air:64043] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64037] PMIX ERROR: UNREACHABLE in file server/pmix_server.c at line 2198
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64037] 4 more processes have sent help message help-mca-bml-r2.txt / unreachable proc
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64037] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64037] 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-runtime.txt / mpi_init:startup:internal-failure
[yozuis-MacBook-Air.local:64037] 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt /
```

I see in [a github post](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/pull/6315) and [this post](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.open-mpi.org//msg33022.html) that the error has been fixed before, but I still got this error.

I have no cs background and find it hard to understand the discussion in the github post. I'd really appreciate explainations on what is going on and help to fix the problem! Thanks.